# Limit Listview Rows to 1?

Tags: c#, listview

Is it possible to limit the number of rows in a listview to 1? I need to mimic a user control that has been created in VB6, into .Net (C#, 4.0), which looks like a text box, but allows dropping of items into the text box, and it shows an item with a small icon (representing the file type) and the name of the file. And as you add more, they fall next to eather other - too many makes them scroll out the side.

I was going to try this with a ListView - is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just limit the number of items programmatically - or if you want drag-and-drop - then use the DragOver event.